# Default python launches even after installing anaconda

Tags: python, linux, anaconda, linux-mint

I have installed anaconda latest version in my LINUX MINT and it's expected that the ANACONDA version of python to launched when I type python/python3 on the terminal but it only start the default ones. How to set it to launch the Anaconda version. conda is installed and is verified by writing conda on the terminal

Comment: What does your `$PATH` look like?

Comment: `which python` and `which python3` will tell you where your OS is looking in order to execute Python code.  You'll probably need to revise your `PATH` variable to stop looking where it's currently looking and to start looking where the conda install put the new python directory.

Comment: bash: /home/username/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-12.0.2//bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin: No such file or directory @C.Nivs

Comment: `condabin` should probably just be `bin`, and you've got an extra `/` next to your `jdk-12.0.2`

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because it can't find `python` in your anaconda folder. `/home/username/anaconda3/condabin` isn't a valid folder name (at least, not on any anaconda installation I've seen), so just rename `condabin` to `bin`. If you edit your `$HOME/.bash_profile`, it should look something like:

```
# added by Anaconda3 5.0.1 installer
export PATH="/home/username/anaconda3/bin:</rest/of/things/here>:$PATH"
```

Restart your terminal and try `python` again